# Sound plays faster than video on YouTube in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, video, youtube

When I go to YouTube and watch some video, usually the sound playing is faster than the video playing, how to solve this?

My computer is Windows XP, video card is ati hd4830, cpu is amd 3 core thing, I think it is fast enough. Video card driver updated.

Not only youtube, but normal video inside computer is also like this....

Comment: Does it happen on other websites as well?

Comment: Try to update the Adobe Flash Player software to the latest available version.

Comment: Is it lag? And does it happen for every video?

Comment: The video is smooth, but the sound cannot catch up.

Comment: what browsers have you tried? Compare experiences w/FF/IE/Chrome to make sure it's not some strange add on you have.

Comment: try toying with the Video card drivers as well (new/old versions). I see major performance problems out of the box with many systems - sometimes it's the VGA driver.